# Is there a way to access a JSON value multi-level deep in one call in jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a multi-level json object like this:

```
{
    employee : {
        name : "Blah",
        company : {
            name : "Company"
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can access company name like employee.company.name, but is there a way to do this dynamically? Like I tried employee["company.name"] But that doesn't work. Basically if I have the string "company.name" I want to get that value in one call.

Comment: The easiest way is to use Lodash/Undescore/Ramda. With Lodash/Underscore it's `_.get(employee, "company.name")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by accessing each sub-object separately:

```
employee["company"]["name"]
```

```js
var data = {
    employee : {
        name : "Blah",
        company : {
            name : "Company"
        }
    }
};

console.log(data["employee"]["company"]["name"]);
```

Comment: avoid answer question marked as duplicate